# SQL Query, Using Same Table Twice

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to  find the film list where two actors are together in a particular film. The correct query to use is the following

```
select f.title from film f
INNER JOIN film_actor fa1 ON f.film_id = fa1.film_id
INNER JOIN film_actor fa2 ON f.film_id = fa2.film_id
INNER JOIN actor a1 ON a1.actor_id = fa1.actor_id
INNER JOIN actor a2 ON a2.actor_id = fa2.actor_id
where 
(a1.first_name = 'CATE' and a1.last_name = 'MCQUEEN')
and
(a2.first_name = 'CUBA' and a2.last_name = 'BIRCH')
```

And the below method doesn't return any result:

```
select f.title from film f
INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
INNER JOIN actor a1 ON a1.actor_id = fa.actor_id
INNER JOIN actor a2 ON a2.actor_id = fa.actor_id
where 
(a1.first_name = 'CATE' and a1.last_name = 'MCQUEEN')
and
(a2.first_name = 'CUBA' and a2.last_name = 'BIRCH')
;
```

Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second query by doing:

```
INNER JOIN actor a1 ON a1.actor_id = fa.actor_id
INNER JOIN actor a2 ON a2.actor_id = fa.actor_id
```

The actors a1 and a2 must be the same as they have the same id which is the value of `fa.actor_id`.

So, then, this actor should also have:

```
first_name = 'CATE' and last_name = 'MCQUEEN'
and
first_name = 'CUBA' and last_name = 'BIRCH'
```

at the same time. Which can't happen.

That's why you need to join it twice with film_actor table so that a1 and a2 can be different.

Comment: I understand now... film_id is the unique identifier, but actor_id shouldn't be... thank you for clearing it up